# How to use md-nav-bar correctly?

Tags: angularjs, navbar, angular-material

I'm using angular material md-nav-bar and i have those problems.

1) I want to add it to the middle of the page.

2) I want to know how to add pages to the nav-items

I have attached an image to show how it looks now
[image]

Is there any possible way to do it?

Any help highly appreciate. Thanks,

Comment: did a few research and the hack may be non-trivial. for instance, md-tabs have an special attribute to do that: https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/api/directive/mdTabs i suggest you to file an issue to the angular material team this is interesting feature and i think it should be present in angular-material.

Comment: @Sombriks i totally agree with you. I have search it many time and i'm unable to find the better solution. I have an question for you is it possible to add logo image above to md-tabs ( as bootstrap nav-bar)?

Comment: Hi @Udara, i never added it directly to tabs , however the docs says that it's possible: https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/api/directive/mdTabs

Answer (score 2):

Here you go - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/vKAYgG?editors=1010#0)

- To centre the `md-nav-bar` use [layout](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction)
- To add a `md-nav-item` use `ng-repeat` with an array and add to the array

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-app="MyApp" layout-fill layout="column" ng-cloak>
  <div layout="row" layout-align="center" flex="70">
    <md-content class="md-padding">
      <md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem" nav-bar-aria-label="navigation links">
        <md-nav-item ng-repeat="item in navItems" md-nav-click="goto('{{item.value}}')" name="{{item.value}}">{{item.label}}</md-nav-item>
      </md-nav-bar>
      <span>{{currentNavItem}}</span>
    </md-content>
  </div>
  <div>
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</md-button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial'])
      .controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

  function AppCtrl($scope, $element, $compile) {
    $scope.currentNavItem = 'page1';

    $scope.navItems = [
      {value: "page1", label: "Page One"},
      {value: "page2", label: "Page Two"},
      {value: "page3", label: "Page Three"},
    ];

    $scope.addItem = function () {
      $scope.navItems.push(
        {
          value: "page" + ($scope.navItems.length + 1),
          label: "Page" + ($scope.navItems.length + 1)
        }
      );
    }
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the navbar elements to the center of the page you can add the `<span flex></span>` tags before the start of the first nav-item and the end of the last nav-item.

For your reference:

```
    <md-nav-bar>

    <span flex></span>

    <md-nav-item>
    </md-nav-item>

    <md-nav-item>
    </md-nav-item>

    <span flex></span>

    </md-nav-bar>
```